# How do I run a constant background thread in a QGIS Plugin using Python?

Tags: python, pyqgis, qgis-3, multithreading

I'm working on a plugin that involves parsing information, and then mapping it. I have a simple gui that allows me to start, stop and choose a file to parse.

I'm trying to separate the parsing function and the main gui/ rendering in hopes that I can have a smoother experience for the user.

Basically the parser puts the parsed information into a queue and the mapping function uses that information and displays it. I have this working without a background thread but I often get "not responding" or it is very slow to interact with the map or the gui. I tried implementing this with python's threading already and I'm still having the same issues.

Are there any better ways to run a background thread for QGIS? Where can I find more information or examples of this being done?

Comment: Have a look at [Tasks - doing heavy work in the background](https://docs.qgis.org/testing/en/docs/pyqgis_developer_cookbook/tasks.html) in the PyQGIS Cookbook.

Comment: I suppose I should have mentioned this in the question but I have tried tasks and maybe I'm misunderstanding them but I cannot run a continuous task in the background. I found that it needed an end and a place to go when it finishes.